# SCSS Not working in my view [Code igniter]

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, sass

My SCSS code is not working in my code igniter project :

```
$custom-file-text: (
  en: "Browse",
  es: "Elegir"
);

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="es">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Seleccions Archivo</label>
</div>
```

The link in my view :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/upload.scss" rel="stylesheet">
```

My css code is working in the files but not the scss.

Maybe I forgot something but I dont see what. I checked on google but I can't found something usefull for my issue.

Comment: Browsers cannot read `scss` files; you need to use a compiler to convert it into a plain `css` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS needs to be compiled into CSS. Link the CSS once you have compiled it! Better yet minify it after compiling it!

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=compile+SCSS